# ADComputerobject OperatingSystem empty

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a small PowerShell script, which should show me the operation system of different Servers in the Active Directory.
All information are in the computer object, but when I get the reply from the PowerShell script it is empty.

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Script:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {name -like "ServerName"} -Properties 'OperatingSystem', 'OperatingSystemVersion' -Server DomainName:Port
```

Output:

```
DistinguishedName      : DistinguishedName      
DNSHostName            : DNSHost.domain
Enabled                : True
Name                   : ServerName
ObjectClass            : computer
ObjectGUID             : ObjectGUID     
OperatingSystem        : 
OperatingSystemVersion : 
SamAccountName         : SAMAccountName$
SID                    : SSID
UserPrincipalName      :
```

Comment: Ask yourself first: is this a PowerShell or Active Directory problem? What do you see in e.g. [ADUC](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc754217(v=ws.11).aspx)?

Comment: @iRon When I use the command on my other virtual maschine I get as output the Operation System, that's the reason why I am so confused.

Comment: Does that concern the same `"ServerName"`?, if not, then you didn't rule out Active Directory (which you could easily/best do yourself). I can think of a lot of AD reasons (replication issues, [join and authentication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961817.aspx) issues, although you suggest with your ?fabricated? DNSHostName, it did join) why this in not filled in and not many PowerShell reasons, considering the rest of the attributes are filled in)

Comment: As iRon says, check in AD Users and Computers to see that that information is actually populated, because you're going to find it's not. In which case, this isn't a powershell/programming issue and as such is offtopic.

Comment: IIRC the computer itself populates that attribute when it joins the domain, so if the computer never joined the domain, the attribute will be empty.

Answer (score 1):

- OperatingSystem
- OperatingSystemHotfix
- OperatingSystemServicePack
- OperatingSystemVersion

as other fields, are not replicated in the Global Catalog (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-operatingsystem and following sections).
Hence you can't get these fields when requesting the GC (-Server DomainName:Port). You can retrieve them only by requesting directly the domain (-Server DomainName).

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem (PS7 with a lot of module), the *OperatingSystem* parameter is available, but hidden. Nevertheless, filtering on *OperatingSystem* is possible but not displaying it

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter { operatingSystem -Like '*Windows Server*'} -Properties operatingSystem -Server $env:USERDNSDOMAIN
```

result is realy filtered !

```
DistinguishedName : CN=SRV-01,OU=Serveurs,DC=contoso,DC=com
DNSHostName       : SRV-01.contoso.com
Enabled           : True
Name              : SRV-01
ObjectClass       : computer
ObjectGUID        : 46306f78-9833-40c2-bb9c-06461462b
OperatingSystem   :
SamAccountName    : SRV-01$
SID               : S-1-5-21-184956565-601246437-303096148-4584
```

to really know the *OperatingSystem* value I read the remote registry `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProductName`